# Увеличение числа полей wp_post и их использование

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

В общем вопрос в следующем: функционала поста WordPress часто не хватает, а использование custom field или плагина advanced custom field считаю жуткой тратой места в бд и неразберихой. Если к примеру сайт полностью заточен под фильмы и во всех постах требуется дополнительное поле, то это явно не рационально. По этому как добавить и использовать дополнительные колонки в самой базе, а именно wp_posts?
Возможно ли это сделать только через расширенный функционал темы, без ковыряния в ядре и т.д. 
Также я понимаю что даже если это получится, вполне возможен "слёт" структуры базы. Но всё же это лучше чем пара ( id (поле - значение)) и так для каждого поста с огромным количеством кастомных полей.
**С советами о написании собственной CMS прошу воздержаться.**

Comment: Та разберись вначале что такое произвольные поля, а то такой бред несёшь. ACF можно не юзать а написать свой плаг. Или взять более простой

Answer (score 0):

Дополнительные поля для этого и придуманы, их использование практически не скажется на быстродействие WP (в разумных, естественно, пределах; иначе, ищите другую CMS).

> использование custom field или плагина advanced custom field считаю жуткой тратой места в бд и неразберихой.

Не могли бы вы пояснить это?
Вам в любом случае придётся тратить место в бд. А насчёт неразберихи - вы ж не "ручками" работаете с БД, какая разница как оно организовано? Для самой системы удобно - а это самое главное. А вот то, что вы хотите *(не зная что и куда)*

> добавить и использовать дополнительные колонки в самой базе, а именно wp_posts

Явно нарушит структуру, и может привести к неправильной работе (или вообще отсутсвие оной :) ).

**P.S.** Вы в курсе, что при первом же обновлении все ваши доп. поля уйдут в небытие? )

Comment: а про P.S. можно подробнее? Вы проверяли или просто предположили?

Comment: Я Вообще то про слёт и писал. "Также я понимаю что даже если это получится, вполне возможен "слёт" структуры базы. "

Comment: А по поводу удобно для самой цмс, если вы не в курсе того о чём говорите, лучше промолчите. В случае с использованием custom fields или улучшением (advanced custom fields) ситуация не меняется, я с базами данных не первый день имею дело. При использование кастомных полей идёт запрос к каждой записи, а это дикия тупость. т.е. при использовании стандартной записи вытаскивания из wp_post (thumbnail, date, author, и т.д.) происходит запрос к массиву данных и вытаскивают из бд массив. А не отдельную запись. И так, судя по вашему ответу лучше сделать десятки или сотни запросов вместо одного?

Comment: @alenkins, предположил, т.к. разработчики WP сами не рекомендуют изменять системные файлы/бд, т.к. они могут быть переписаны при обновлении

Comment: @VladimirH, Специально для вас я уточнил: (в разумных, естественно, пределах; иначе, ищите другую CMS)

Comment: @VladimirH, "А по поводу удобно для самой цмс, если вы не в курсе того о чём говорите, лучше промолчите."
Мне кажется это вы не понимаете о чём говорите. Думаете разработчики не подумали о дополнительной **допустимой** нагрузке? Или, мне кажется, вы не совсем понимаете что WP - не самая оптимизированная система. И если вы гонитесь за оптимизацией то вы выбрали не ту CMS

Comment: Как вариант - создавайте свою таблицу с первичным ключом, равным ID поста, и пишите функции-обертки для обращения к ней. Потому что даже если вы добавите свои колонки к wp_post, все равно придется делать дополнительный запрос для считывания данных из ваших колонок (вы же не будете "ковыряться в ядре").

Comment: @Николай понятное дело что там не дураки, сама CMS изначально не заточена под обилие полей для поста, так бы и было больше заморочек, каждому надо своё, одному в колонке надо хранить цифры, другому true false, третьему ещё что и т.д. вот и разделили на дополнительное поле. Но это явно не рационально для использования, запрос к каждой записи новым запросом я к этой "удобности". А я спрашиваю о возможности не влезая в ядро и чисто функционально вытаскивать строку из бд одним запросом.

Comment: Вот @Ponio уже что-то дельное предложил ) Хотелось бы ещё узнать в какую сторону смотреть (касательно функций) или ссылку вообще замечательно бы было.

Comment: @VladimirH, класс `wpdb` к вашим услугам: http://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb